# Iron Ruby in Windows Visual Studio

Tags: ruby, winforms, visual-studio, ironruby, ruby-in-steel

I have been attempting to create a Windows Application using Iron Ruby Version 1.1 and Ruby in Steel for Windows Visual Studio 2010. I have attempted many times to start a new Iron Ruby Windows Application project. I am able to create such a project, however, upon creation, the project is merely a .rb file. My question is how can I create a Windows Form file in [Design] mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iron Ruby lacks any support for a designer in WinForms, currently. You'll have to manually code it, much of what the designer is doing for you.

Someone [wrote a tool](http://ironshay.com/post/winforms-in-ironruby.aspx) to convert C# designer code into Ruby, but that's as much support for a WinForms designer as Iron Ruby has.

There may be designer functionality support added later, either third party or official, but nothing exists like that right now. There is some [promising progress](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/IronRuby-Visual-Form-Designer) though.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth reply. The main reason I was expecting such a form was because of this video I ran across: http://tinyurl.com/82twbsq Any idea what this fellow has going on, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst Visual Studio with Ruby in Steel does not have support for designing Windows Forms you could try using SharpDevelop at least for the Windows Forms code generation. [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/) has support for [creating Windows Forms projects in IronRuby](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2009/10/04/IronRubyIntegrationInSharpDevelop31.aspx) and also has a forms designer that will generate IronRuby code.

As far as I am aware the IronRuby support that SapphireSteel were working on was [stopped](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Blog/Goodbye-IronRuby-Hello-Ruby-In) and they are concentrating on standard Ruby.